# I have created a portscanner using java, but when i click execute it just freezes

Tags: java, for-loop, freeze, port-scanning

The code below is what i am using to create a port scanner, but however, when i click "scan" it executes but the gui freezes until it finishes the scan, is there any possible way to allow it execute other actions whilst scanning?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class PortScannerGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JPanel Panel = new JPanel(null);
JTextField Field = new JTextField();
JButton Button = new JButton();
JTextArea Area = new JTextArea();
JButton limit = new JButton("limit");

public PortScannerGUI()
{
    super();
    setSize(350, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    LoadUI();
}

public void LoadUI()
{
    Area.setBounds(20, 50, 310, 310);
    Area.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
    Area.setEditable(false);

    Field.setBounds(20, 10, 200, 35);

    Button.setBounds(230, 10,100, 35);
    Button.setText("Scan");
    Button.addActionListener(this);

    Panel.add(Field);
    Panel.add(Area);
    Panel.add(Button);
    add(Panel);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    PortScannerGUI Main = new PortScannerGUI();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
{
    Thread Runner = new Thread();
    Runner.start();
    int j=0;
    String str = Field.getText();
    for(int i=1;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if(str.substring(i-1, i).equals("."))
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
    if(!str.equals("") || j==4 || j==6)
    {
        try
        {
            InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getByName(str);
            PortScanner P = new PortScanner(IP);
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not an IP address");
    }

}
}
```

This top code is the code for the GUI part and below is the code that actually scans the ports..

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.InetAddress;

import java.net.Socket;

public class PortScanner
{
public PortScanner(InetAddress iA)
{
    for (int port = 1; port <= 65535; port++)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket s = new Socket(iA, port);
            System.out.println("Port " + port + " is open");
            s.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a classic example of doing a long-running process in the Swing event thread (the EDT or Event Dispatch Thread) and thus freezing this thread rendering your GUI non-functional. We see this sort of thing posted time and time again, and the solution is the same and is relatively simple: do the long-running process in a background thread such as can be provided by a SwingWorker. For more on this, please read up on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), or search similar problems on this site, because again, it is discussed a lot.

Another point regarding your code, **never** do this:

```
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
```

If you ignore exceptions, you're literally flying blind. At the very least, print a stack trace, i.e.,:

```
    catch(IOException e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Same for here:

```
     try {
        InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getByName(str);
        PortScanner P = new PortScanner(IP);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  // **** add this!
     }
```

Myself, I'd set up the PortScanner object in the PortScanner constructor, but would run the scan in a separate public method, say called `scan()`. This would allow me to set up the PortScanner object on the event thread and then scan it in a background thread by calling its `scan()` method. Sometimes this is more convenient.

**Edit**
I'd also give the PortScanner class the ability to have a PropertyChangeListener added to it, so that it can allow other classes to listen to it for changes, including information on the ports. This way you can publish the PortScanner port information in the GUI. The simplest way to do this is to have your PortScanner object extend SwingWorker since SwingWorkers come with PropertyChangeSupport built in. Then you could use the publish/process method pair to publish the port information to the GUI rather than printing it out in a println statement. The tutorial that I've linked to above describes how to do this, and we can help with the details if you get stuck.

Comment: @user1576203: please see edit. As for "alterations", we generally don't write your code alterations for you, but rather help you with specific questions. You should read and understand the tutorial first as it will guide you in what you have to do. Then go ahead and try to create your own SwingWorker and if you get stuck post another question on stack overflow.